# Excluding 3dots additional to other characters with regex in a string

Tags: regex

I have such an http-url detector regex:

```
(?:http|https)(?::\/{2}[\w]+)(?:[\/|\.]?)(?:[^\s<"]*)
```

It works pretty well for the following url representation:

```
http://www.acer.com/clearfi/download/
```

What kind of modification I can do to extract

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml2450
```

from

```
Huanghhttp://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml2450...)()()()()()
```

?

Comment: is this `...)()()()()()` actual ending?

Comment: yes, it is the actual ending of the line.

Comment: responses are not working? why? please comment answers, update your question or validate an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it to capture:

1. group of http stuff
2. followed by (group of) subdomain stuff
3. followed by as many as possible groups of:

   - one point or slash
   - followed by a group of characters (non-point, non-space, non-`"`, non-`<`)

[`(?:http|https)(?:\/{2}[\w]+)([\/|\.][^\s<"\.]+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/vSbUP7/1)

I made capturing groups to visualize the results

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your expression here and there: `(.*)(https?:\/{2}[\w]+[\/|\.]?[^\s<"]*)(\.{3}.*)` and get only second capturing group from it. See example here: https://regex101.com/r/0viPC5/2

This expression probably can be simplified further but I don't know your exact input and search criteria so let's stick with what you already wrote.